# Magento make MySQL crash 1 or 2 times every day

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, innodb, magento-1.9

I'm currently running a Magento Store on community edition (CE) 1.9.X.X.

The store perfectly run last few months (we have launch the website november 2014).

The last 2-3 weeks, MySQL start crashing every day. I have analyzed SQL logs of Magento, I have activated the system.log and exceptions.log to see if something special was happening but there was nothing...

Currently, what MySQL is saying when it crashes is :

```
150127 14:29:50 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150127 14:29:50 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2015-01-27 14:29:58 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-01-27 14:29:58 11145 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-01-27 14:29:59 7f4395db8720 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-01-27 14:29:59 11145 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-01-27 14:29:59 11145 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-01-27 14:29:59 11145 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-01-27 14:29:59 11145 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-01-27 14:29:59 11145 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-01-27 14:29:59 11145 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-01-27 14:29:59 11145 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-01-27 14:29:59 11145 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 5.0G
2015-01-27 14:30:24 11145 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-01-27 14:30:24 11145 [ERROR] InnoDB:  InnoDB: Unable to allocate memory of size 2147484264.

2015-01-27 14:30:24 7f4395db8720  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139928253728544 in file ha_innodb.cc line 17106
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
19:30:24 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68245 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x8cd6c5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x494)[0x661af4]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf710)[0x7f439599b710]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7f4394646625]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x7f4394647e05]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9658f3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9ad927]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9a3083]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa215aa]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x96c09d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x48)[0x5a8458]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x6e7aa1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0xbf6)[0x6eb6f6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x59b22d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x3e5)[0x5a01d5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7f4394632d5d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x5925b5]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

I'm running Magento on a dedicated server using WHM/CPanel.

Here is my my.cnf (custom my.cnf, anything else is default from MySQL on WHM) :

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
bind-address=127.0.0.1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G
open_files_limit=10000
innodb_open_files=300
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size=1G
query_cache_limit=256M
max_allowed_packet=512M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=4096M
innodb_log_buffer_size=2048M
bulk_insert_buffer_size=512M
```

I don't really know what is happening right now. Hope someone can help me tracking this and find THE problem.

When the MySQL server crash, I receive an email from the server :

```
Time:                    Wed Jan 28 09:28:45 2015 -0500
1 Min Load Avg:          7.91
5 Min Load Avg:          6.15
15 Min Load Avg:         3.27
Running/Total Processes: 9/398
```

And multiple script are using 96% of the CPU :

```
root      3351  0.0  0.0  76720  5956 ?        Ss   Jan22   0:31 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 root      8111  0.0  0.0  79560 10316 ?        S    08:16   0:00  \_ /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl /usr/local/cpanel/bin/leechprotect
 nobody   18857  0.0  0.0  77440  6364 ?        S    08:48   0:00  \_ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 user  32031 96.0  5.1 1812740 1702668 ?     R    09:21   7:12  |   \_ /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/magento/index.php
 nobody   21687  0.0  0.0  77420  6216 ?        S    08:55   0:00  \_ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 nobody   27499  0.0  0.0  77568  6360 ?        S    09:11   0:00  \_ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 user  32707 95.6  3.8 1373164 1259928 ?     R    09:23   5:30  |   \_ /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/magento/index.php
 nobody   27937  0.0  0.0  77420  6220 ?        S    09:12   0:00  \_ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 nobody   28499  0.0  0.0  77432  6248 ?        S    09:13   0:00  \_ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 user  31897 96.1  5.4 1902860 1793256 ?     R    09:20   7:29  |   \_ /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/magento/index.php
 nobody   29172  0.0  0.0  77436  6220 ?        S    09:14   0:00  \_ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 user   2873  0.0  0.0 127356 22328 ?        R    09:28   0:00  |   \_ /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/magento/index.php
 nobody   29201  0.0  0.0  77104  5264 ?        S    09:14   0:00  \_ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 user  32215 96.1  4.7 1679356 1568032 ?     R    09:21   6:44  |   \_ /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/magento/index.php
 nobody   29223  0.0  0.0  77120  5756 ?        S    09:14   0:00  \_ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 user  32035 96.2  5.1 1800248 1690280 ?     R    09:21   7:12  |   \_ /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/magento/index.php
 nobody   29241  0.0  0.0  77432  6224 ?        S    09:14   0:00  \_ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 nobody   29245  0.0  0.0  77432  6228 ?        S    09:14   0:00  \_ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 nobody   29247  0.0  0.0  77432  6212 ?        S    09:14   0:00  \_ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 user  31646 96.1  6.1 2126108 2018664 ?     R    09:20   8:10  |   \_ /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/magento/index.php
 nobody   29257  0.0  0.0  77436  6252 ?        S    09:14   0:00  \_ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 nobody   29261  0.0  0.0  77112  5748 ?        S    09:14   0:00  \_ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
 user  31460 96.1  6.5 2249252 2142760 ?     R    09:19   8:30  |   \_ /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/magento/index.php
```

Thanks,
santerref.

Comment: Are you using the absolute latest MySQL stable version? Does this also happen on an equivalent version of MariaDB?

Comment: I can't really reproduce what is happening because I don't know what it is happening... I can't tell you if it happen on an equivalent version of MariaDB. I have a local version of the website and it never happen. But currenlty I'm the only one using it for development purpose only.

Comment: Make sure you have enough memory.  Looks like you may be maxing out the memory allocation.  The Magento database will grow over time (specifically the log tables).  Try clearing out the log tables, and disabling logging to the database following this article: http://www.axertion.com/tutorials/2012/12/how-to-disable-magento-logging-to-the-database/

Comment: As always, keep a close eye on `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see what you're doing in there.

Comment: I have this hell problem too. If you find any solution please notify me.

Comment: See my answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was with the logging. One table was too large and takes too much time to load.

To solve my problem, I emptied the table `log_visitor_online` and enabled **Log Cleaning** every day in **System » Configuration » Advanced » System » Log**.

CRON must be enabled, otherwise log cleaning will not work and the table will still continue to increase.